# Creating NFT Marketplace on Ethereum like OpenSea

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, markets

I am honored to have a chance to deal with talented Blockchain programmer.
I am creating my own NFT marketplace base on Ethereum.
In this platform I will sell all NFTs in Blockchain.

But I face some problems.

1.
How to get all NFTs in Blockchain network?
In my site user can browse NFTs by category.
The biggest problem is that to get all NFTs by category.
example: Animal Category=> monkey NFTs, mouse NFTs etc.

2.
How to buy and sell NFT in my Market platform?
I've already done mint my NFT token and Buy / Sell my own NFTs.
But how can I buy / sell other user's NFTs?

Please write any answer or any opinion about my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: 1/ Create your own database or use a third party provider. 2/ See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98826/how-does-a-nft-market-work